# How many different words of length $12$ can I build using $0,1,2$ symbols

Tags: combinatorics

I think I know the answer because its about cycle, but I'm wondering where my intuition failed if we have $2^n$ binary words of length $N$ shouldn't we have also $3^n$ words which we can build using $3$ symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. For words of increasing lengths made of three symbols $(0, 1, 2)$, we have:

1. $0, 1, 2$ $\text{ (3 words)}$
2. $00, 01, 02, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22 \text{ (9 words)}$
3. $000, 001, 002, 010, 011, 012, etc. \text{  (27 words)}$
4. I think you can see the pattern.

Since there are three choices for each letter in a word, the number of possible 12 letter words is $3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3\times 3 = 3^{12} = 531441$ words.